# Cannot find DLL from Project Reference in dotnetcore 5 with F5 or release / publish builds

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild

I have a csproj file with nothing out of the ordinary

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>AppService</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>AppService</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference ..../>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Datastore\Datastore.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```

Note the `ProjectReference` on the third line from the bottom of the file -

Both projects build fine - if I run `dotnet build` followed by `dotnet run`, everything is fine - however, if I try to run the code generated by the publish profile or even F5 - I get a CLR binding error:

[image]

I don't understand what is going on nor where to look. It's not an incorrect format error like many of the other questions.

Comment: Can you share what the Datastore.csproj roughly looks like or do you have a minimal sample that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I'm not 100% sure it is the cause but when I open VS-code solution directory from a symlink - I get the repro - when I opened the directory in VS-code from the actual path, all was fine. A lot of time was lost here :-P